# Chain of Responsibility design

Tags: python

I'm trying to design a chain of responsibility pattern.

It slightly differ from traditional way when handler does only one action on a request, f.e. handles http response considering status code.

But my handlers have to do two actions. Below is an (dummy) example where handler asks a question first and then writes the user response to some store:

```
# some object where we keep surname and name 
class Request:
    pass


# some outer storage
store = {}


# chain of responsibility implementation

class PersonIdentifier:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.handlers = []

    def add_handler(self, handler):
        if self.handlers:
            self.handlers[-1].set_next_handler(handler)
        self.handlers.append(handler)

    def handle(self, request):
        return self.handlers[0].handle_request(request)


# handlers for chain of responsibility

class BaseHandler:
    handler_name = None

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.next_handler = None

    def set_next_handler(self, handler):
        self.next_handler = handler


class SurnameHandler(BaseHandler):
    handler_name = 'surname'
    handler_name_answer = 'surname-answer'
    question = 'Type your surname: '

    def handle_request(self, request):
        if request.handler_name == self.handler_name:
            return self.question
        elif request.handler_name == self.handler_name_answer:
            global store
            store['surname'] = request.surname
            del request.surname
            request.handler_name = 'name'
            return self.next_handler.handle_request(request)
        else:
            return self.next_handler.handle_request(request)


class NameHandler(BaseHandler):
    handler_name = 'name'
    handler_name_answer = 'name-answer'
    question = 'Type your name: '

    def handle_request(self, request):
        if request.handler_name == self.handler_name:
            return self.question
        elif request.handler_name == self.handler_name_answer:
            global store
            store['name'] = request.name


user_request = Request()

chain = PersonIdentifier()
chain.add_handler(SurnameHandler())
chain.add_handler(NameHandler())

# first ask for surname
user_request.handler_name = 'surname'
surname = input(chain.handle(user_request))
user_request.handler_name = 'surname-answer'
user_request.surname = surname

# then ask for name
name = input(chain.handle(user_request))
user_request.name = name
user_request.handler_name = 'name-answer'
chain.handle(user_request)

print(store)
```

It looks ugly for me. What do I dislike more is using **handler_name** and **handler_name_answer**.

May be you could offer nicer way to solve my task?

Answer (score 1):

*Chain of Responsibility* pattern (hereby "CORP") includes two things: iteration and "handling".

IMO, the iteration part, at least in modern programming languages such as Python and Java, can be easily "extracted" to an external iteration. So eventually the code could look like:

```
result = None
for handler in handlers:
  temp_result = handler.handle(request)
  if temp_result is not None:
    result = temp_result
    break
if result is not None:
  # handled!
```

I think this approach is simpler than maintaining the inner chain, and it has the same impact.

In CORP, once a handler was found, and it can handle the input, no additional handlers should be executed. It's quite similar to filtering.

However, I think that the code we have in your question tries to execute **as many handlers as it can** (as it tries to enrich a wider context). So maybe CORP is not really needed here.

Perhaps you can have enriching classes, that have a method `enrich` that accepts a request and a context, so that every enriching class could either change the state of the context object, or leave it as is:

```
class BaseEnricher:
  def enrich(request, store):
    pass
```